# How to center an image in my web browser?

Tags: jquery, html

**UPDATED**.

I want to center an image in a webpage **both horizontally and vertically**. I tried using the following JQuery and I can't figure out what I'm doing wrong.

The webpage is here:
http://aaa.sr

This is the JQuery I'm using:
andreaslagerkvist.com/jquery/center/

I've put the js file here:
aaa.sr/jquery.center.js

I'm new here so this website allows me to post only one link in my question. Any help is appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something as simple as this would do the trick. I decided to leave my answer (The others are correct) not only to show a solution to your current problem, but also to suggest scrapping the paragraph tag (It isn't necessary) and to suggest adding an alt description to your image tag.

This css:

```
#container {text-align: center;}
```

And this html:

```
<div id="container"> 
 <img src="http://aaa.sr/aaasr.png" alt="Fil donya lazim tikabbar, Fil net mafeesh gheir aaa.sr">
</div>
```

Should be all you need for a website this simple.

Answer (score 1):

Why use JQuery to center an image. There are load of methods to center an image, like putting it in a `div` with `text-align:center` or displaying it as a block and assigning `auto` left and right margins. This is just plain old CSS.

Comment: Thanks.  I want to center it both horizontally and vertically.  The JQuery I suggested would have done this. Is it still doable with CSS?

Answer (score 1):

It would be easier to just use CSS.

```
p > img { margin: 0 auto }
```

Answer (score 1):

Major problem:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.3.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://aaa.sr/jquery.center.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$('#my-element').plugIn();
</script>

    </body>
```

All of the spaces are actually non-breaking spaces, which causes parse errors. The [HTML validator](http://validator.w3.org/) will detect this!

Comment: Not directly related, but saving the webpage as UTF-8 and serving as ISO-8859-1 is also recipe for trouble.